# Blurry icons panel in LibreOffice

Tags: linux-mint, libreoffice

I have a pesky problem with LibreOffice.
By some reason all icons on panel are blurry and difficult to see, as you can see in the screenshot below:
[image]

Unfortunately, I did not find any explanation or remedy for this upon quick search.
If anyone can point out to me how to fix this [**on Ubuntu-based distro**], it will be greatly appreciated!
P.S. I have a Zotero add-on installed in the Writer and its icons look sharp, in contrast to neighbouring icons on the panel.

Comment: Have you tried a [different icon set](https://www.libreofficehelp.com/change-libreoffice-default-look-and-feel/)?

Comment: I have only two icon sets: Tango and Colibre, they both look very blurred and ugly.

Comment: That was the only thing I could think of. They look as though they've been stretched to a larger size. You can try making them smaller. I just checked and, at least with my eyes, they are still easy enough to see.

Comment: the icons are low resolution, not blurry ... you really need to identify the actual problem if you want to get good results from internet searches